# Trying to get this to run the for-loop whenever an error is not caught, what do I add?

Tags: python

I have a script here to check for an error, and I want to make it so that if it doesn't find one it runs the for loop again. What do I add after the last line?

```
with open("apacheErrorLog.rtf","r")as f_obj:
    lines = f_obj.readlines()
for line in lines:
        print(line.rstrip())
try:
    with open("apacheErrorLog.rtf","r")as f_obj:
            lines = f_obj.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    
        print(f_name , "not found")
else:
    for line in lines:
```

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate over the contents 3 times in the first place, and why aren't you iterating over the file itself instead of reading the entire contents into memory with `readlines`?

Comment: @chepner Idk lol I didn't write this it's part of an assignment and it says to paste this in. I've had to fix multiple errors in it already though because my teacher apparently doesn't check what he puts in his assignments I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I don't think you actually want to start the loop until after you have checked if the file exists.

```
def main():
    try:
        with open("apacheErrorLog.rtf","r")as f_obj:
            lines = f_obj.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f_name , "not found")
        return
    
    for line in lines:
        print(line.strip())

main()
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could put the for-loop under an else statement and remove the return.